# What's the meaning of the phrase "class always tells"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I saw the sentence "class always tells" for the second time and know nothing about of what it means. It barely make sense for me. I tried to google it, but didn't succeed in. So, if anyone could explain me the definition, I would be greatly thankful :)

Comment: Having "class" -- a sort of sophistication -- always "tells" (as in a gambler's "tell" -- something that is visible to observers).

Answer (score 2):

*Class* here refers the quality of a person, or, sometimes, thing.

> She is a classy person

means, as an opinion, that *she* has superior behavior, deportment, or, perhaps accomplishment.  In this sense, *class** is a positive opinion of someone or something. There is no recognized scale of measure.

> class always tells

means that whatever qualities  a person determines as  *having class or are classy* cannot be hidden. The person determined to have class will demonstrate that class no matter the situation.
An infrequent use of "class always tells" "class will tell"  would involve some thing.

> This Diberg radio was expensive, but it has performed perfectly for 30 years. Class will tell, I suppose.

This use is not so common as use with people.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the word *tells* means "reveals itself," as in intransitive sense 1 at the [Merriam-Webster site](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell).

The expression means that when you deal with high-class people, you can always recognize that fact about them.

Until I saw other posts and comments, it did not occur to me to discuss the word "class" explicitly. I agree with the tendency in that discussion, that social and economic classes are intended, such as "the wealthy" or "the poor," sense 2 at the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/class) site. And whether judgments about class are true or polite, they seem widely shared, and also to explain [certain words](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parvenu) for people who behave like members of a class that they do not actually occupy.

Comment: Yes, tells does mean to reveal in this sense. However, I and probably most English speakers today do not recognize social class.  Wealth or influence seems not to equate to class very much these days. ,

Comment: @J.Taylor Since when does wealth or influence not determine class? I was unaware of this transition. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Perhaps J. Taylor means to say that he knows of some wealthy vulgarians or some poor people with refined characters.

Comment: 50 years ago text books on socio-economic matters  defined "classes" based on affluence or  wealth. I recall being indifferent to that; already terms other than "class" were in use. "Lower classes" is rarely used today, same for "upper classes"., rarely as compared to previous times. Today "middle classes" is commonly used, but doesn't seem well defined; same for "working classes". I'm not sure what social or economic value those terms have. Newer terms are in common use: Advantaged, disadvantaged, less affluent , affluent, well to do, etc. Today, when I hear of a "higher class person",

Comment: I tend to think of a person of admired deportment or accomplishment, with economics aside. Today in my experience, a wealthy person is far more likely to be referred to as "Mr. Big Bucks" or "she who has many coin" than "high class"..

Comment: Yes, Chaim, I do. And I think many others, also.

Comment: @J.Taylor I'm not sure when to drop it. I think we're close to that moment. But the original question was the meaning of the words "class always tells." If you take "class" to refer to someone's behavior, then the expression means that you can tell how someone is behaving. That observation would be trivial. The expression means that someone's behavior reveals something else about that person -- his background.

Comment: Chaim, I agree we are getting to the end. I am quite willing  to accept what you have written, but, also what I have written. Ain't English wonderful. We can read the same thing, and nuance our way, and away....We need a book to straighten all this out, and I doubt either one of us is ready to write it today

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above, except that I think "class" (here, social class) could refer to either high or low class - "class always tells" in the sense that aristocrats or wealthy people are expected to behave in better or more sophisticated ways, or alternatively in that poor people are expected to behave less well or in less sophisticated ways. This is a fairly old-fashioned statement in most of the English-speaking world these days (even people who think it might hesitate to say it in public) and often contradicted by reality.

Comment: Yep.  I am sure the phrase began as a reference to social class.  That would be rare today.. I hear it almost exclusively now as referring to accomplishment, or skill.

Comment: Have you evidence to support your claim?

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, which is the claim which needs support?